# Jquery relative dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code has 2 dropdowns -> categories and subcategories. sub Categories are dependable on selection of categories. Now problem arise when we have 3 pairs of dropdown. Like if I change first dropdown's category it will change all 3 sub categorie's dropdown values.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.cat_select', function(e) {          
  $(this).closest().find('.subcat_select').find('option:not(:first)').remove();
  $(this).closest().find('.subcat_select').append(data.html);
  //data.html comes from an ajax request.
  
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="cat_select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="subcat_select">
      // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="cat_select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="subcat_select">
      // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="cat_select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="subcat_select">
      // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are having same class for all dropdown and you use the same class in jQuery. so it happens

Comment: I know that, that's why i came here for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a selector in your `closest()` call to get a specific parent. Alternatively, `.parent().parent()` should also work in this case.

```js
var data = { html: "<option>test</option>" }; //data.html comes from an ajax request.

$(document).on('change', '.cat_select', function(e) {
 $(this).closest('.row').find('.subcat_select').find('option:not(:first)').remove();
 $(this).closest('.row').find('.subcat_select').append(data.html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="cat_select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="subcat_select">
      // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="cat_select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="subcat_select">
      // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="cat_select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="subcat_select">
      // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-sm-5"><select>Cateogry Select</select></div><div class="col-sm-5"><select>sub Cateogry Select</select></div>. Its like that. So it will not work i guess.

Comment: @JimKasprowicz A bit late, but I edited it to your new HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <select class="cat_select" data-parfor="1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>

  <select class="subcat_select" data-subfor="1">
    // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select class="cat_select" data-parfor="2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>

  <select class="subcat_select" data-subfor="2">
    // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select class="cat_select" data-parfor="3">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>

  <select class="subcat_select" data-subfor="3">
    // Result will come on selection of cat_select.
  </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.cat_select').on('change', function(e) {     
    var $select = $(this);
    var fornumber = $select.attr('data-parfor');
    $('.subcat_select[data-subfor="'+fornumber+'"]').find('option:not(:first)').remove();
    $('.subcat_select[data-subfor="'+fornumber+'"]').append(data.html);
    //data.html comes from an ajax request.
});
```

Adding the data-parfor attribute and the data-subfor attribute allows you to use the same css class, which means less styling and instead, the selector in JS uses the value of the clicked elements' attribute for the target.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/328854/

Comment: Agreed, that will work also. but here I have one div only. (2 dropdown). A user can clone and add as much dropdown as he wants. So not possible to add data attributes to them.

Comment: @JimKasprowicz : That's easy, just enumerate through the drop-downs at add the attributes. Inside the function you're using to add/clone, you can n+1 the attribute number. This method also allows you to change the layout/structure of the html without having to re-work JS.